# Is two-wheeled luggage still available?

Tags: luggage

The first luggage store I went to in Sydney only had four-wheel luggage, apart from a few weird monstrosities that hardly looked like luggage (it kind of looked like a backpack), and the store staff told me that two-wheeled luggage is pretty much unavailable nowadays. Is that the case, or is two-wheeled luggage still available?

I'm looking to buy in-store, not online.

Related question, from 2012: [Suitcases: hard or soft?  Canvas, polycarbonate or something else?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/suitcases-hard-or-soft-canvas-polycarbonate-or-something-else)

Comment: How is a back-pack not luggage? Can you please put in a more precise and less negative description?

Comment: Maybe tangential, but what exactly is your goal? Saving additional weight from two extra wheels? Other than that, any four-wheeled suitcase I have seen could also be used as a two-wheeled one.

Comment: I bought a suitcase with just 2 wheels last autumn, and there were plenty to choose from, so I don't expect they were on their way out of the market. I must admit that I haven't paid attention since.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper luggage that won't run away from me.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, like [this luggage](http://discworld.wikia.com/wiki/The_Luggage)?

Comment: Aren't most small suitcases two wheeled?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper for a given price point I've found the two-wheel sort to last longer.  The castering of the 4-wheel type introduces an additional; failure mode which wears quickly and is vulnerable to knocks

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the two wheel ones are much much better. First, they have two large wheels fixed on the sides (usually) which makes them last longer and steady when you pull it, not four small annoying little wheels, if for any reason one of them went out of balance you will get all kinds of noises and it will be hard to pull/push it along.. annoying as hell.

Comment: I fully agree with the people saying that two-wheels is more comfortable. I also fully agree with this being off-topic. Anecdotical: I bought a two-wheels mid-large trolley bag this year (I think sometime between Easter and June). Made by Travelite, iirc.

Answer (score 4):

They appear to become more rare. Even models which had two wheels are often getting replaced by 4-wheel versions, now often called *spinners*. It's a new fashion and they seem to sell people on ease of movement, despite being less sturdy, less space efficient and often heavier than 2-wheel versions.

Last time I went into a suitcase store, about 3 months ago, there were a few 2-wheel models, mostly for sizes below 25", so I ended up getting a hybrid with two large wheels and two small wheels 31". I can see the online storefront for some local specialty stores and department stores here in Montreal still offer a few 2-wheel suitcase, the keyword to find them is *roller suitcase*, although some 4-wheel results appear too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two-wheeled luggage is still available from numerous manufacturers. Personally I use a Tumi Alpha 2 International, which is most definitely still available from Tumi, and this is just one of dozens of such bags from multiple manufacturers.

If your question is related to where to buy such a product, this is [outside of the scope](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) of questions that should be asked on Travel.SE.