# What kind of bag can I use to travel with a baby car seat?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, automobiles, children, child-safety-seats

I need to carry a baby car seat on an international air trip. The car seat's dimensions are 28.5 x 17.5 x 30.9 inches and it looks like this:

[image: baby car seat]

I'm having trouble finding an appropriate bag for carrying it. The best option I've found so far was a military style duffle bag, like these ones, the largest of which has dimensions of 30" x 50" (diameter by height):

[image: military duffle bags]

Are these bags large enough to hold the car seat on an air travel?

Comment: Are you traveling with an infant?

Comment: @Karlson No, only me and my pregnant wife.

Comment: Have you looked at native bags for the manufacturer? http://www.themegababies.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=IABOVIACARSEAT&gdftrk=gdfV24785_a_7c1993_a_7c6191_a_7cIABOVIACARSEAT&gclid=CJXbu8HR8rUCFZCf4Aodhn8AUw

Comment: I assume you want to bring it as checked buggage?

Comment: Whenever we traveled with e.g. Swiss, we received a heavy-duty orange plastic bag at check-in to stow our car seat. We never had any issues (not all airlines will give you one, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching a lot, I eventually found a very large duffel bag, from Outdoor Products, that was perfect for the job. Actually, the bag is so large that there was enough room for more things, such as clothes, toys and other stuff. Here's how it looks, with the car seat inside:

[image]

I have already made the trip and everything went fine. But I do recommend that anyone with the same kind of luggage also wrap the bag in plastic (as others have suggested) at the airport. The base of the car seat is made mainly of plastic and may get damaged in the transport.

Comment: I often see these things ripped up on the luggage carousel. More protection is better.

Comment: does this have an online link where we can see the specs of this item? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest wrapping it in plastic. This will make it good to be checked lugagge. Plastic wrapping is good for weird shaped luggage and in your case it is a perfect fit for that. Also, it is cheap and available in almost every airport. Check [this question about plastic-wrapping luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3220/why-would-you-wrap-your-luggage-in-plastic) for more details.

Comment: Do all airline companies allow this? I've heard that some don't allow you to check anything but bags. Cardboard boxes, for example, wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo I never heard of an airlines that does not allow this, but everything is possible.