# What Happens When a Wrapped Luggage is Opened by Security?

Tags: luggage, airport-security

Some airports have machines to [wrap luggage in plastic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3220/why-would-you-wrap-your-luggage-in-plastic). Now, security can open luggage to look into it for security reasons.

What does security do if they want to open a wrapped suitcase or box? Do they re-wrap it? Tape it?

Comment: Depends on the airport and country...

Comment: 99% of the time, they open suitcases **not** in presence of the owner. I usually find a note saying something meaning *this suitcase was searched*. Now I just got a new suitcase, so I thought of wrapping it next time to keep it in good condition.

Comment: @pnuts - Never seen a suitcase opened *after* the journey. Why would they? The threat of something going into the plane is over. Suitcases are almost always inspected after passing the X-ray machine on the way to the cargo hold. You are right though that sometimes this is done in the presence of the owner. Most times, it is not.

Comment: @pnuts - You are right. They do that on arrival here in Montreal but it is very rare. This happened to me exactly once over at least 100 arrivals. One of my locked suitcase gets searched at least once out of two times at some point during the trip. It is *always* the suitcase that holds my tripod, so I know what looks suspicious :) and I always make sure not to pack anything fragile in the same suitcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark mentioned it does depend on the airport and country, but as a general rule, the inspectors are only required to repack your items back into the suitcase they came out of.  The plastic wrap is a disposable item and even if they slowly and carefully unwrapped it, it would be near impossible to rewrap.  So plastic wrap would be tossed by any inspection after you have checked your bags.

If you have something like a cardboard box and the plastic wrap was keeping it shut, then the inspector would likely use tape to close the box after completing the inspection.