# What is the incidence of lost luggage in Amsterdam Airport?

Tags: luggage, amsterdam, ams

Years ago, 10% of luggage going through Amsterdam Airport was lost.  Is that still true?  We have a choice to fly through Paris or Amsterdam to Prague on Delta.

Comment: Which airline, which Paris airport as alternative and will it be on a busy day?

Comment: _'Is that still true?'_ - Was it ever true? It's certainly not true now. Do you have a source for that, is is it possibly just an urban myth?

Comment: By "years ago", are you referring to the 1920's? :)

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/what-is-the-probability-of-true-lost-baggage-never-returned-to-owner?r=SearchResults&s=1|48.1442

Comment: Small dataset, but I arrived many times at Schiphol airport and not once I or a colleague lost our luggage.

Comment: Pick no layover if you really care about bags, but even that's not a certainty so if it matters to you a plan B is still pretty important.

Comment: IME the claim is nonsense, assuming it refers to anything post-1980s. You really need to provide a citation for the (dubious) claim; also when *"Years ago"* refers to: 1960s? Was it an anecdote? official statistic? internet copypasta? Was it some peak number during a strike? freak weather? OTOH, Heathrow is a nightmare, esp. during the frequent strikes, freak weather, peak times (Christmas) etc.

Comment: Two pieces of advice: (1) Expect baggage to be lost: keep precious items and a change with you (at least a change of undies), (2) Ensure the connection is long enough for baggage to be transferred, years ago I flew through Orly regularly and every 45min connection resulted in delayed (not lost) luggage.

Comment: I have tons of Dutch friends/coworkers and I have never once ever heard of lost luggage at AMS. But I have personally experienced it at Heathrow, ORD, etc. IME it has much more to do with the class of ticket, and (US) airlines have been treating non-status passengers flying on consolidator fares badly post-2001. The claim about Amsterdam is totally bogus AFAIK and should be removed or at minimum substantiated.

Comment: This is absolute nonsense. No one would fly on Amsterdam if there was a 1/10 chance of losing your luggage every time. Yet it’s the world’s 5th biggest airport in terms of traffic.

Comment: from personal experience, the rate of lost luggage at Amsterdam is miniscule. Over the last 25 years or more and hundreds of flights, me and my family have not had a single bag lost there. Once a piece of luggage was put on the wrong flight out of Amsterdam but this was recovered within hours, and sent out on the next flight to the same destination, arriving in Sao Paulo only some 3 hours after my father did. Only other problem I've had in Amsterdam was a suitcase being damaged in the underground railway station, through no fault of the airport (a wheel cracked getting it out of a train).

Comment: For every stats regarding lost luggage, we necessarily need to know whether it was irrecoverable lost or just went stray and was found and returned later.

Comment: Consider the risk of strikes (*grèves*) before flying through France.  I would recommend to find a non-stop flight to somewhere in Central Europe, then continue by train (as an added bonus, this limits the climate impact too).

Comment: Not an answer since I can't back it up with facts, but: I've been traveling from Amsterdam to the UC/Canada every year since 2006 and only had once incident where my case arrived an hour late. Also: I prefer Amsterdam to Paris any day due to better amenities (for me) ;)

Comment: As everyone has said, 10% is plain wrong.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That’s a bit worrying - a known way to get your bags into a flight you’re not on...

Comment: I don’t see why this is closed as “needs more focus” when OP is very clearly asking exactly one question. Sure, there’s the claim about 10% loss rate at some unspecified point in the past which I agree sounds wildly unlikely, but that’s only *mentioned* as a motivation for the question. OP isn’t asking about that. They’re asking what the current loss rate is, and nothing else. It’s perfectly well focused, even if misguided.

Comment: Can people stop repeating they have flown frequently to or from Amsterdam and never lost luggage? So have I but the question is about transit, where luggage gets lost more frequently.

Comment: I have always lost luggage, had it delayed, or had my own transit delayed **every** time I have flown through Paris CDG. I would always choose Schiphol or Heathrow as my transit airport of choice.

Answer (score 22):

According to [this article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travel-truths/What-happens-to-lost-luggage/) the rate of bags lost in Europe is about 8 per thousand. That's less than 1%.

It goes on to say that 85% of bags reported as missing are delivered within 48 hours.

Choose your layover on whatever basis you like, but lost bags shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Note that there is no contradiction between the two statements "the rate of bags lost in Europe is about 0.8%" and "the rate of bags lost in Amsterdam airport is 10%".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Mathematically, no, but a reasonable person will be able to infer than a modern airport like schiphol won't lose 10x more bags than the european average

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: yes there is a contradiction. If AMS were in fact 12x worse than European average, people simply wouldn't fly through it. Yet it is the #2 passenger airport in Europe (after LHR).

Comment: @smci: That isn’t really a contradiction — it’s like saying “if Ryanair and EasyJet really were much more uncomfortable than airlines like BA, people simply wouldn’t fly with them.”  Many people willingly accept risks or discomfort for the sake of price, convenience, and the like.  And frankly, my anecdotal experience suggests Schiphol is significantly worse than average: in the half-dozen or so times I’ve flown through Schiphol, my luggage has gone astray twice, whereas in probably over a hundred other flights within Europe in the last five years, I’ve never lost luggage elsewhere.

Comment: @PLL: yes it is; all other things being equal, people would instantly replace Schiphol with Rotterdam, Brussels, Düsseldorf, Frankfurt etc. if it wasn't doing the job, except for the small set of people for whom it was their final destination. As to your experience,  I've never heard any bad stories about full-fare carriers at Schiphol, which airline (LCC?) were you using? Ryanair uses contract baggage-handlers, so if you had a bad experience at Schiphol with Ryanair, that's more to do with Ryanair's Schiphol baggage-handling subcontractor, than Schiphol itself.

Comment: “…other things being equal…” — the point is that they aren’t usually equal at all.  Re my experience: iirc it was once with Norwegian, once with Turkish Airlines; and I don’t want to suggest extrapolating too much, n=6 is not a statistically meaningful  sample. My point is just that that Federico Poloni’s concern is not as irrelevant as you are suggesting: it’s perfectly plausible that Schiphol could be significantly worse than the Europeans average.

Comment: Other things are equal, until proven otherwise: noone has produced a shred of evidence that Schiphol's baggage-handling is any worse than other European airport, let alone 50%, let alone 2x, let alone the absurd 10x claimed which would put any airport (with competitors) out of business near-instantly. The burden-of-proof is on the OP to substantiate their "10x" claim, and define the missing "Years ago...". And as to how Schiphol could remain the #2-ranked in Europe if any of this was true...

Comment: Waiting for my luggage at Schiphol recently I noticed there were 3 or 4 handling companies delivering to the same luggage band. So even if one of them underperforms, the others can more than make up for them.

Comment: @smci: If I or OP was claiming some specific other rate, then agreed, the burden of proof would be on us.  But that’s not what either of us is doing.  The OP is *asking* what the current rate is (based on a memory of a possible past figure); and I’m supporting Federico Poloni in pointing out that this answer is far from definitive, that it’s *very plausible* that Schiphol could have a significantly worse rate than the average (or better, for that matter).  Now you’re saying that this highly unlikely, because if it were the case, Schiphol wouldn’t be so successful. [cont’d]

Comment: @PLL: OP explicitly claims "Years ago, 10% of luggage going through Amsterdam Airport was lost." Sounds like a specific rate to me.

Comment: [cont’d] But major airports vary in many obvious ways that are at least as important as baggage handling reliability: geographical location, traffic capacity, costs to airlines, quality of terminal facilities, and more.  Some major airports certainly are notably worse than others on some of these aspects; so Schiphol could comfortably have worse baggage handling, but remain competitive based on other aspects.

Comment: @smci Ryanair has very good statistics for lost baggage.  The only times I lost baggage was with KLM and BA.  The difference is that Ryanair *only* flies point-to-point, so provided they get the luggage on the right plane, and get it out of the plane, it is hard to get lost.  KLM and BA will check baggage through to final destination - and it is at the layover that the baggage will be lost.

Comment: Guys, Guys, Guys, Guys, Guys, Guys .. the luggage is anyway ONLY TRANSFERRING at AMS.  **And the actual question being asked is "Any difference between AMS and CDG?"**  (Obviously the answer is "no, of course not")

Comment: @smci Have you actually been to Rotterdam or Berlin? You cannot realistically transit there, they are not competing for Amsterdam's hub position. London, Paris, Frankfurt, Madrid, maybe Brussels but not Rotterdam! Ryanair is similarly irrelevant, they do not even offer connections. I do not believe the 10% figure but yes airports can be worse than others, at least for a time (CDG was, some 10-15 years ago but that's too old to find a proper source).

Answer (score 17):

I cannot imagine 10% of luggage ever misconnected in AMS.  This just seems *sooooo* much higher than anywhere else.  Moreover, it would imply that KLM as the major user of the airport would have a rate of mishandle luggage at around 10%, which would have put them in an untenable business situation.

More importantly, what matters is the mishandled rate now, not way back when: the rate for 2017 was 5.57 per thousands, and Delta now uses technology where they claim to handle 99.9% of all bags perfectly (as reported by the BBC [here](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-48437262)).  Given that AMS is a major Delta hub, and KLM is so intertwined with Delta, it is unlikely that the DL performance is much worse than announced when connecting to a KLM flight.

As an aside: I avoid CDG as much as I can.  I have always found AMS to be much more passenger friendly: clean, with a logical layout, and spacious wait areas, all things which CDG is NOT.

Comment: KLM intertwined with Delta? It used to be, but it's now part of Air France.

Comment: @MSalters It's technically part of *Air France–KLM* which is still a strong partner of Delta with a [transatlantic joint venture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Air_Lines#Joint_ventures).

Comment: @MSalters in fact AF/KLM and Delta operate as a single company on TATL flights through this joint venture.  AF/KLM is also implementing this radio tracking system for luggage to be deployed in 2020 (this year).

Comment: CDG also has the issue of being in France, where strikes (*grèves*) are relatively common.

Comment: bravo on your last paragraph, @ZeroTheHero !  It's amazing more people have not mentioned this.  You would never in a million years fly through CDG if you have the option of Amsterdam (or ........... anywhere).  Heathrow (I can't even stand typing it) and CDG are the two Worst Things In The Galaxy.

Answer (score 8):

Last year I was part of the software team of sections of the baggage handling at Schiphol. From the data I saw there they never reached the 10% you claim. The year I was working the number of lost bags was 0.75%. Which is lower than the European average of 0.8%. Though that might be because of the number of significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

From my own limited experience (fly once or twice a year, always from Amsterdam), luggage handling was very bad in the '90 but is good now. 
On returning home i hardly ever have to wait more then 15 mins for the luggage to arrive on the belt. Only once had two bags misplaced, they were sent after us on the next plane, this was about 15yrs ago.

It used to be in the '90 we had to wait for 45 mins normally and very often they would forget to unload or would only unload half the suitcases. Than after complaints and some more waiting the rest would come.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated the loss rate you quote is probably a misquote, and these days probably irrelevant. Faster connections <1h increase the risk of luggage missing the connection, but they'll send it to you on the next flight. **So if you're worried about late bags, pick the airport with the longer layover.** Or better yet, plan your flight so the connection has 2h-3h as a layover.

On a personal note, i agree with the comments that AMS nicer than CDG, but that is personal taste. Also AMS is more in English then CDG, which is french after all.

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember from years back when there was a strike or a system failure there was a huge backlog of luggage in Schiphol, it may even have happened a few times when they were installing the current luggage system.

But that was years ago and I have not heard about system failures for a long time.
If there was a 10% luggage delivery failure it was to deliver in a timely manner, all delayed luggage got send on bar for a small percentage which had lost tags.
It was also always short in duration, like a 24 hour strike.
So while there might have been a time when the 10% luggage lost was mentioned in the news, it was never a long term number.

Strikes can happen but are much less likely in the Netherlands than in France, so based on that alone I would avoid Paris.

I have written this answer from memory, living near enough the airport that news like that makes the small, free, local newspapers and the local gossip.

Answer (score -1):

1. The 10% figure was/is total nonsense
2. It seems like on the order of 1 to 10 in 1000 bags get **delayed** or put on the **wrong** flight.  They're not lost, you just get them **late**.

(Example, I once flew from Paris -> HK -> Sydney, and by mistake they sent the bags to HK.  They dropped them off to me in Syd. the next day.)

3. Regarding profoundly lost bags (perhaps stolen, or just utterly lost - you never, ever get them back).  This is extremely rare.
4. Regarding Paris versus Amsterdam on the issue of delayed baggage.  **Absolutely no difference whatsoever.**
5. Note that if the baggage gets delayed, that will very likely be ***due to the airport you start in***, New York or whatever.  For example someone simply pressing the wrong button or entering the wrong code.  The "middle airport" would not affect this much.

The general answer to your question is simply that there is **utterly no difference in choice** between Amsterdam and Paris in terms of the luggage issue.

---

Purely FYI: Never, ever, EVER fly to or through CDG!

CDG is a hellhole, and Amsterdam is one of the two top of the world's very-large airports.  So choose Amsterdam!

Note that even if you're ***going TO PARIS*** for a holiday, for goodness sake, fly to somewhere awesome like Lyon, Zurich, etc. and take a train or drive in to Paris!  CDG non.  (The only thing worse than CDG itself, is, the commute from CDG to Paris!)