# Can I strap a small bag to my backpack so that it still counts as one bag?

Tags: luggage, legal, international-travel, singapore-airlines

I'm going on an international flight via Singapore airlines and I was wondering can you strap a smaller bag onto the front of a pack and will it class as one bag?

Comment: It still counts as one bag.  Source: Personal experience.

Comment: What airline are you flying on? Stuff that would be ignored at Turkish Airlines will be immediately noticed by Ryanair, for example.

Comment: Singapore Airlines

Comment: Singapore airlines is one of the more lenient airlines. Also keep in mind you are allowed a personal item in addition to your carry on.  Lastly, airline policy is one thing, enforcement by staff is another

Comment: when you strap the smaller bag onto another pack, yes it becomes "one bag" in effect.  But then the dimensions come into play.  You could fit the smaller bag into the larger one if it becomes a problem

Comment: Are you planning to carry both on?  Or is this about checked bags, in which case I would make sure they are well attached because if the small bag comes loose it will not have a destination tag attached.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not strapping two bags together will make them count as one piece of luggage will depend on the luggage policy of the airline. It is safe to assume that low cost carriers, or other airlines with strict luggage policy enforcement, will try to charge you for the extra piece of luggage. This will also depend on how evident the strapping procedure is. For example there exist some hiking rucksacks which are made up of a large pack combined with a smaller everyday backpack. These can usually be solidly strapped together in a way that renders it hard to distinguish them from one another. Chances are that these rucksacks don't get flagged as being to pieces of luggage.

One trick I've already suggested here on Travel SE is to [wrap your construction in plastic film so that the whole thing becomes one unique piece of luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/41746/22140). Another similar strategy could be to put your two packs into a large duffel bag to be checked in. This will hide your ruse and solve the luggage count problem. Do check that the combined weight of the packs does not exceed your carrier's limitations or else you'll be billed for another reason.