# Is baggage wrap a waste of money?

Tags: luggage, damaged-luggage

My checked bag(s) have been opened on every flight from/to USA and on some others.  So I would think plastic wrap would be a waste of money.  Especially if it increases the probability of inspection ("maybe this guy is trying to hide something").

Comment: My latest trip, a shopping trolley with stroller size wheels had one of them bent even though they had bars "protecting" them from impact.

Comment: This is opinion based and although I have personally always avoided paying for the wrap, it was explained to me that it helps hold the luggage together in the unfortunate event where the locks or zip get broken and it happens. It is not mainly against theft, for that it is useless. Still I am a probability guy so I take my chances.

Comment: If you are using the exact same luggage, it's likely there is some characteristic about the bag itself that appears suspicious.

Comment: 1. It's opinion based. 2. Even then it depends on the price of wrapping (and the content of your suitcase). Wrap for 1 _money_ may be considered as reasonable while the same wrap in the same airport  for 25 _moneys_ would be considered as waste of money.

Comment: see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3220/why-would-you-wrap-your-luggage-in-plastic

Comment: @KateGregory: that link revealed a good idea: turning two or more small items into one to save checking fees.

Comment: Maybe the wrap will cover the pro-drug-abuse stickers and other hints that your luggage merits special attention from the authorities.

Comment: Ha! Anyone that stupid is going to get caught anyway.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well:

> My checked bag(s) have been opened on **every** flight from/to USA and on
>   some others

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Scope of the plastic wrap is to preserve your baggage from scratches and to keep things inside in case of zip/lock failures, so if it's worthy is up to every one's taste.

But, given your premises, it's clearly and objectively a total waste of money because it will never be able to fulfill its task.