# Johannesburg airport international transfers with baggage not checked through

Tags: transit, luggage, international-travel, jnb

We are flying to Jo'burg with BA and then on to Madagascar with SAA (3 hrs later). BA will not check the baggage through to my final destination.
We could travel with carry-on baggage only on BA but will have to check it in as hold baggage for the flight with SAA because of their more limited carry on allowance.
Can I recheck my baggage at the International transfer desk, ie without going through immigration and check-in?

Thanks
Jmidds

Comment: According to [this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/13420/583), it looks like you do need to go through passport control and customs to recheck your baggage.

Comment: Thanks for your help.......we have 3 hrs between flights so I guess we should make it!

Answer (score 3):

No, at JNB you cannot have the transfer desk transfer your luggage, so you will need to enter South Africa, collect the luggage and re-check it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.......we have 3 hrs between flights so I guess we should make it!